# Not Showing integer values in crystal report formula field

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, vb.net-2010, crystal-reports-2010

I am Working In VB.Net net Crystal Report, In that I need to sum a column values (integer)and display in the formula field . the problem is when the sum exceeds 10000 it shows like #### ,I Tried Format option in property but its not working , please somebody help me ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
It is not the problem with formatting.
```

Increase the size of the `filed` which you are using to display the value, then it will show the value.

Answer (score 0):

Simply other option is you can set true "Can Grow" property of object. This will automatically expand if minimum width is exceed.

http://www.allaboutreports.com/index.php/tag/can-grow/

http://docs.imis.com/15.2/index.htm#!tipsandtrickscrystalreports.htm